# Is this container implementation totally sensible?

Tags: c++, templates, class-design

Would you write the following simple container any other way or it's totally sensible as it is:

```
template <typename T, bool small_>
struct TransType
{
   typedef const T& param_type;
};

template <typename T>
struct TransType<T, true>
{
   typedef const T param_type;
};

template <class T>
class Container:public TransType<T,sizeof(T)<=sizeof(void*)> {
 public:
  param_type getVal(){
   return obj;
  }
  void setVal(param_type input){
   containment=input;
  }
 private:
  T containment;
};
```

Comment: `template <typename T> void UB() { TransType<T, sizeof(T)<=sizeof(void*)>* x = new Container<T>; delete x; // undefined behavior }` :P (Base classes either need public virtual destructors or protected non-virtual destructors.)

Comment: One drawback is that is doesn't compile ;)

Comment: @GMan: or make the inheritance private. *Public* base classes either need public virtual destructors or protected non-virtual destructors. Or a documented ban on using the base class for polymorphic delete, which is what the standard libraries go with, and which is more or less awkward depending what the base class is for. I don't think many programs have ever failed due to someone casting something to `std::iterator` to delete it.

Comment: What is the purpose of this container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [Boost.CallTraits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/utility/call_traits.htm). Namely, `boost::call_traits<T>::param_type`.

You shouldn't need the client to specify whether the type is small or not, that's the metafunction's job. Nor is there really a need to inherit from anything.

In fact your code right now is **ill-formed**. Because `param_type` isn't a dependent type, the lookup is done without taking into consideration the base class; and will not be found. You'd need to either explicitly qualify it with the base class, add a using-directive, or re-typedef it.

You just want to end up with:

```
template <typename T>
struct Container
{
    //typedef typename boost::call_traits<T>::param_type param_type;
    typedef typename TransType<T>::param_type param_type;

    // ...
};
```

By:

```
namespace detail
{
    template <typename T, bool small_>
    struct TransType
    {
       typedef const T& param_type;
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct TransType<T, true>
    {
       typedef const T param_type;
    };
}

template <typename T>
struct TransType<T>
{
   typedef detail::TransType<T, sizeof(T)<=sizeof(void*)> param_type;
};
```

Now the condition is automatic, and there's no base class hassle.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't inherit from the metafunction.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from GMan's comment about needing an explicit destructor in one form or another, does the added complexity gain you significant performance? The standard library seemed to think that it was up to the user to store an appropriate type in the container such that copying in some cases wasn't a bottleneck.

Comment: Since a copy is *going* to take place, I think this pre-optimization is actually very probably pointless.  The question that I have is, is it harmful?